# Can't upgrade from SQL 2008 R2 Evaluation to Workgroup

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 server with SQL Server 2008 R2 Evaluation edition. I am trying to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 Workgroup edition and having a problem.

When installing I get the error:

> Rule "SQL Server 2008 edition upgrade" failed.
>
> The Selected SQL Server instance does not meet upgrade matrix requirements.'

According to the [Microsoft Upgrade Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx) I needed to uninstall Analysis Services (which I did), but I still get the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the real answer was that I was given the SQL Server 2008 Workgroup disk, not the SQL Server 2008R2 Workgroup disk.

SQL server cant' downgrade from 2008R2 to just straight 2008, so really there was no system error, just user error.

Answer (score 0):

had this error:

```
---------------------------
Rule Check Result
---------------------------
Rule "SQL Server 2008 edition upgrade" failed.

The selected SQL Server instance does not meet upgrade matrix requirements.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

on a upgrade 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise.

My issue what that I started the wrong SQL Server Installation Center 
The right one is the R2 at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\x64\LandingPage.exe"